# ReactJS failed on compile: module 'react' not found

Tags: reactjs

I am stuck with whit compile-time error:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@restart/context/forwardRef.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react' in 'C:\IdeaProjects\ai\node_modules\@restart\context'
```

The app has stopped to work suddenly, removing existing changes from last working iteration didn't help. Folder "../node_modules/@restart/context" is in place and is not empty. I tried to deleting package-lock.json and reinstalling, removing all modules and reinstalling, the error persisted.

How can I solve the situation?

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {Trans, withTranslation} from 'react-i18next'
import {Header} from "./components/Header";
import {C2A} from "./components/C2A";
import {DecorationOptions} from "./components/DecorationOptions";
import {ImagesGallery} from "./components/SwipeGallery";


function App({t}) {
    return (
    <div id="main">
        <Header/>
        <div className="text_wrapper">
            <p><Trans i18nKey='intro1'/></p>
            <p><Trans i18nKey='intro2'/></p>
            <C2A/>
        </div>

        <div id="bg-img1" className="background_image" />

        <DecorationOptions/>

        <div id="bg-img2" className="background_image"/>

        <ImagesGallery/>

        <div id="temp_separator">
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withTranslation('common')(App);
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ai",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "i18next": "^17.0.11",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^3.0.3",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.11",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-i18next": "^10.12.2",
    "react-image-gallery": "^0.9.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the (roughly) canonical solution of blowing away `node_modules` and re-installing?

Comment: Your package.json is missing the `react` dependency, simply run npm install react --save

Comment: @GiladBar: You were right, thanks a lot! Would you like to write an answer? Do you have any idea how the change could have happened?

Comment: Yeah, I will :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your package.json is missing the react dependency, simply run `npm install react --save`. Basically there's no reason or anything that can remove this dependency from the package.json, other than deleting it or running `npm remove react`

Comment: I have still no idea how the removal could have happened. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try [`npm install react`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react) which is missing in your `dependencies` of `package.json`.

Consider using [`create-react-app`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started) as a react boilerplate.

Comment: I have used CRA.